# Issues with xdg-desktop-portal-gnome (file save dialog) using Firefox (103-111) (snap and apt) and Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome, firefox, dialog

I've been having some mildly infuriating issues with saving files in firefox versions 103-111.  I've tried installing firefox via both apt and snap and the problem seems to persist with both:

**Issue #1:**
The **file save dialog**, which I believe is controlled by xdg-desktop-portal-gnome, intermittently crashes sometimes when I try to save a file in firefox.  It seems to be stuck in a loop of openning the dialog over and over again, possibly hundreds of times.  This is evident by a dark shadow behind the dialog box/window and uses up a full cpu core when I open up the system monitor.

***Temporary solution:*** Killing the xdg-desktop-portal-gnome, solves the problem, but doesn't stop it from randomly happening sometime in the future.

**Issue #2**
I two partitions of my ssd drive mounted in two different directories, one at "/a" and one at "/b". Within the **file save dialog** (xdg-desktop-portal-gnome), I can navigate to /b and subfolders within /b, however, when I try to save a file again, the file save dialog automatically defaults to some randomish folder under "/run/user/1000/doc".  I know this is some sort of issue with mounting and whatnot, but I'm not sure how to fix it.  Example pics are below.

Thanks for all your help!

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm having the same problem as Issue #1. This is the only other report of the issue that I've been able to find. Did you ever find a more permanent fix? I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.

Comment: No, permanent solution, I just open up system manager and kill xdg-desktop-portal-gnome, and that way I at least don't have to close firefox.  I haven't figured out a pattern either; sometimes (maybe about 25% of the time) the 'file save dialog' crashes and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Ahh, oh well. Thanks for letting me know.